Как в Unity сделать так, чтобы объект на котором вы стоите при ходьбе персонажа двигался в другую сторону?
Я новичок. Пытаюсь сделать 2D игру. Сделала круглый камень с круговым коллайдером, добавила компонент Rigidbody. Персонаж докатывает камень до стены, тут всё хорошо. Но если запрыгнуть на камень и стоя на нём бежать в сторону стены упираясь в неё то он от стены не отодвигается, приклеился и всё. Что можно сделать чтобы когда я стою на камне и бегу в сторону стены, он как бы двигался в противоположную сторону от движения персонажа? Пробовала поиграть с настройками, но не помогло.
